# Generate different artifacts team city

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a project which I want to deploy via team city but when it builds I want to generate a number of different artifacts.

In my app.config file I have an app setting called "platform" which I want to change the value of for each artifact. For example on build I would get three artifacts, dev, test, staging which would have had the "platform" setting changed to the corresponding value.

I have created the powershell script and run it successfully outside of team city, but I have not been able to work out how to set the file directory where the app.config exists within team city.

Is there a system variable I can use to target the current builds app.config file? Or is there a different / better way that I can accomplish what I want to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a different / better way that I can accomplish what I want to do?

While this sort of question can lead to an argument over which is better...  Based on what you have described, I believe that [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) would be a good fit.  Octopus Deploy integrates very nicely with TeamCity, and it handles the transformation configurations that are required to allow deployment to each of your environments, i.e. Dev, Test, and Staging.  You would simply configure these as Environments within your Octopus Configuration, and during installation, Octopus can modify the configuration files as required, based on variables that you define.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to create 3 build steps inside your TeamCity configuration :

Inside the `Parameters` tab, you can define configuration parameters. Just define here the 3 values : ie: `PlatformDev`, `PlatformTest`, `PlatformStaging`

## Using Visual Studio Runner

You might be using Visual Studio runner type. So, here you can add specific values from MSBuild properties:

1. Dev Step:

Passing the parameter `Dev`, and executing your code

```
/p:CustomPlatform="%PlatformDev%"
```

2. Test Step:

Passing the parameter `Test`, and executing your code.

```
/p:CustomPlatform="%PlatformTest%"
```

3. Staging Step:

Passing the parameter `Staging`, and executing your code.

```
/p:CustomPlatform="%PlatformStaging%"
```

Then, the value CustomPlatform would be accessible inside your MSBuild scripts.

## Using Powershell hand-made scripts

If you are using a powershell script to run your compilation/artifact creation, you can just add this `CustomPlatform` as a parameter of your script, and use it directly.

## Using XSLT

Another way to do this might be to use XSLT to transform you app.config file, using a specific value.